# What is the value of an empty text input box?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement a search box. The following is the code (both HTML and JS)

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchVar" class="searchbox">
    <input type="button" value="Search" ng-click="Search()" class="button">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var Search = function() {

/* code to implement the table content loading part */    
//The following is what I have to filter out the table contents based on input in the text field

     if (($scope.searchVar) && (tableContent[i].indexOf($scope.searchVar) !== -1)) {
          ItemsToDisplay.push(tableContent[i])
     }  
    //Call function to load table
}
```

What is happening is that, if I enter some string into the input text field, the search algorithm works fine and only the relevant items are displayed. However, if I clear the contents of the search box and click on Search button, nothing is displayed in the table. That is, when the text field is cleared and clicked on the search button, it is as if ItemsToDisplay is empty and the if condition fails.

Can someone explain why this is the case? And how I can solve this?

Comment: Form control values are always strings. The default value is the empty string. It seems you're using AngularJS, you might want to add a tag for that.

Comment: I tried checking for === "" and still won't work. How do I check for an empty string?

Comment: the Default value is 'undefined'. while checking u can give undefined without single or double quotes

Comment: Do you know how to set a debug break in your favorite browser (chrome for example) and debug the javascript? Or use console.log() to write debug messages?

Comment: It is good practice to define an input field with `value=""` which is what it will have in modern browsers as default

Comment: use if string length grater then 0, so it will work when you enter the string in the textbox, if empty ,"if" statement does't trigger

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I used the === 0 check and it worked!      I am not able to debug or use console as I am developing for a windows 10 application and I don't know how to attach a debugger from VS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your indexOf($searchVar) you should check that searchVar is != ''. Otherwise no item will be displayed afterward. A suggestion, javascript has a really great console.log functionality that will help you a lot when it comes to if branches

Answer (score 0):

If you cleared input, the value of $scope.searchVar willbe undefined and your condition

```
 if (($scope.searchVar) && (tableContent[i].indexOf($scope.searchVar) !== -1))         {...}
```

will be false, so you didn't push into ItemsToDisplay and nothing append.

I suggest you to write an else statement :

```
if (($scope.searchVar) && (tableContent[i].indexOf($scope.searchVar) !== -1))         {...} 
else {
     ItemsToDisplay.push(tableContent[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try with,

```
if (($scope.searchVar) != undefined)
```

or

```
if (typeof ($scope.searchVar) != 'undefined')
```

Answer (score 0):

> when you do not enter anything in INPUT box then its value become UNDEFINED.
>   you will have to check in if() condition, if input is **undefined** then write your logic, if input has some **value** then write your logic.

```
<form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchVar" class="searchbox">
        <input type="button" value="Search" ng-click="Search()" class="button">
    </form>

    var Search = function() 
    {
         if ( $scope.searchVar == undefined){
            //Do something, input box is undefined 
         } 
         if (($scope.searchVar) && (tableContent[i].indexOf($scope.searchVar) !== -1)) {
                            ItemsToDisplay.push(tableContent[i]);
         }
    }
```